# Как внести данные JSON? python

Tags: python, json

Есть JSON следующего строения:

```
[
   {"id":"1"},
   {"id":"2"}
]
```

Как сюда можно добавить третий элемент, чтобы получилось вот так:

```
[
   {"id":"1"},
   {"id":"2"},
   {"id":"3"}

]
```

Comment: Считать json, получится список из словарей, добавить в список еще один словарь, выгрузить в json список словарей

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Декодируйте JSON в Python-объект, добавьте в него новые данные, а затем закодируйте обратно. Всё это Вы можете сделать с помощью стандартного модуля [`json`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html).

***Пример:***

```py
import json

s = '[{"id":"1"},{"id":"2"}]'

d = json.loads(s)
d.append({'id': '3'})

s = json.dumps(d)
print(s)
```

***stdout:***

```py
[{"id": "1"}, {"id": "2"}, {"id": "3"}]
```